# C++ multiline textbox overflow in windows form

Tags: c++, forms, memory, textbox, multiline

I have a log textbox in my program, whose contents grow bigger and bigger as long as the program runs. I didn't have time to test it myself but I was wondering how does the textbox handle tons of text. Will it run out of memory or somehow automatically free some of it? If it is not done automatically, what is the best way to handle this myself rather than just clearing the log from time to time?

Edit: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 CLR Project with Windows forms

Comment: Which platform? Which UI framework?

Comment: @RemyLebeau as I've said, that's windows forms. Should have mentioned other stuff as well. Anyway, it is done in the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A texbox will simply accept more and more text until it runs out of available memory. To mitigate that, you can set a cap in your code for how many characters/lines you choose to display. Once you reach the cap, remove older data before adding new data.

Otherwise, if you need to display all possible text while minimizing memory usage, consider re-thinking your UI strategy.

For example, I have an app that displays log files that may be up to multiple GB in size. I use a virtual ListView to display the text, where I keep the *visible* text buffered in memory, and (un)load *non-visual* text dynamically as the user scrolls around the ListView. That keeps memory usage down to just a few MB at most, while still providing access to the entire log.

You might consider doing something similar.  Use a file or database to store log data that the user does not immediately see, and load that data on an as-needed basis when the user needs to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a linked list of your log data for this.
For example:

```
struct LogData{
 int time;
 Int catagory;
 char * string;
}
struct LogNode {
LogData data;
LogNode* nextLog;
}
```

You intilized nextLog with NULL and when you have another thing you want to log you create a new LogNode and initlize it with your LogData and NULL. heap allocation is recommended when you don't know how much data you really need. By saving a pointer to the first logNode you can access all log nodes.

A textbox realloc memory when needed. since its on the heap the textbox does not need to know how much memory will it use and as the name dynamic allocation suggest it can alloc memory dynamically.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked at all

Comment: The question is unclear as you can probably tell. From what I understand he is asking about how he should  lay the data of his log.

Comment: the OP's question is very clear, actually. How does a **textbox** handle lots of text? Does a **textbox** run out of memory, or does it clear memory? You didn't answer any of that. The OP didn't ask how to manage his log data in memory. Not to mention, a linked list may be fast for insertions/deletions, but it is not very efficient in general when lots of data is involved, especially when traversing that data.

Comment: I think the answer for that is simple it reallocates memory when needed.